# How can you implement "temporary placeholders" in data structures?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, types, compilation, architecture

*I am trying to boil down a pretty complicated problem into its essence so I can get some help on how to model or architect it. Here it goes.*

Say we are compiling functions in this order:

```
function test() {
  sum(mul(2, 3), mul(3, 4))
}

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

function mul(a, b) {
  return a * b
}
```

We end up with an AST something like this:

```
{
  type: 'Program',
  blocks: [
    {
      type: 'Function',
      name: 'test',
      args: [],
      body: [
        {
          type: 'Call',
          function: 'sum',
          args: [
            {
              type: 'Call',
              function: 'mul',
              ...
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'Function',
      name: 'mul',
      args: ...,
      body: ...
    },
    {
      type: 'Function',
      name: 'sum',
      args: ...,
      body: ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Now we start compiling this AST into more easily manipulated objects, with direct pointers to functions and such. The final result might look like this:

```
{
  type: 'Program',
  blocks: [
    {
      type: 'Function',
      name: 'test',
      args: [],
      body: [
        {
          type: 'Call',
          pointer: 2,
          args: [
            {
              type: 'Call',
              pointer: 1,
              ...
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'Function',
      name: 'mul',
      args: ...,
      body: ...
    },
    {
      type: 'Function',
      name: 'sum',
      args: ...,
      body: ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The main difference is that the "final" version has a *pointer* to the index where the function is defined. *This is a very rough sketch.* The reality would be there could be multiple passes required to resolve some context sensitivity, and so you end up with multiple partial/intermediate data structures in the transition from the AST to the final compiled object.

How do you make types to deal with this situation? The ideal is that there is an "initial" and a "final" type. The reality is that on our *first pass*, we have a "placeholder type" for the function calls, which we can't resolve until we have completed our first pass. So on the first pass, we have:

```
function: String
```

On the second pass we change it to:

```
pointer: Int
```

How do you reconcile this? How do you architect the algorithm so as to allow for these "placeholder" types for the final data structure?

I have tried searching the web for these sorts of topics but haven't found anything:

- partial types
- intermediate types
- placeholder types
- virtual types
- temporary types
- transitional types
- how to have temporary placeholders in data structures
- etc.

Comment: There are multiple ways this could be done. One could be to store the additional processing information outside the actual AST. Another could be using something like `Call { function: Either<Function, FunctionRef> }`. You could push this further and perhaps embrace an idea where a node is always encapsulated in a monad that either contains the address of a node or the node itself. The client would call `nodeRef.get()` or something to resolve the underlying value. E.g. `NodeRef<T>` a bit like `Optional`, `Future`, etc.

Comment: @plalx oh I like where this is going, mind explaining more in an answer how to apply those concepts? I am not super familiar with functional programming, but wonder what the JSON or pseudo code might look like to implement this.

Comment: Is it a typed language? Are you shape shifting nodes all the time or mostly swap a node for a reference to a node and vice versa?

Comment: It is a typed language (with implicit and explicit types). Sometimes you start from AST and can directly build a final IR object from the AST object, but other times you need to wait until all the _other_ IR objects are constructed so you can determine (in a context-sensitive way) how to convert the remaining AST nodes into IR too. This might be iterative you might have to do 5 or 10 passes to get everything resolved. For example, context-sensitive syntactic sugar waits until surrounding code is converted to IR, then we can tell how to resolve the AST sugar.

Comment: Once you get to the final IR object graph, you don't need to have this intermediate system anymore. It's only necessary during the transition.

Comment: What tends to vary in these IRs. Here the variation is that you reference a pointer rather than the Function node itself. If IR mutates in arbitrary ways then it may prove to be difficult to find a way to abstract all those mutations other than declaring each transition type explicitly. Is there a general concept for that iterative transition phase? I assumed IR meant intermediary reprensatation but reading that again it seems to be a bad interpretation on my end.

Comment: IR is intermediate representation. It usually just goes straight from AST to IR, IR doesn't change for all intents and purposes after it gets created. It's just that the transition from AST to IR in some parts may be delayed a few passes.

Comment: Well, the question is a little too abstract for an explicit answer. If the multiple passes are all made by the same class then perhaps that class could aggregate the necessary transitional state in another data structure next to the AST. If the process is handled by a pipeline of collaborators then you may try to standardize that transitional structure to be passed through the pipeline along with the AST.

Comment: But, if the main thing that differentiate a transitionnal AST representation and the final IR representation is that properties either reference a node OR a node reference then you could introduce a generic `NodeRef<T>` wrapper which either contains the node or know how to get the reference to a node.

Comment: If you can give more examples of AST --> perhaps we could help. This looks like a fun problem, but we need much more details ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a hashmap.

In a first pass write name/index pairs to the hashmap without modifying the AST itself. For the example that would result in this hashmap (represented in JSON format):

```
{
    "mul": 1,
    "sum": 2
}
```

In a second pass you can use the hashmap to replace references to the keys of this hashmap with a `pointer` property that gets the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not trying to understand how to store intermediate data types, but understanding how to store "references" or "holes". Go look up how a typical serialization/deserialization algorithm works (especially one that can deal with something like repeated substructure or circular references): http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/mirror/c++-faq/serialization.html

It may give you helpful ideas.